# Wpf Listbox bigger than the window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I'm learning wpf/c#, and to apply what I learned about the differents wpf layout. I tried to build a simple employees list/details window, but I have I little problem :

the listbox height is larger than the height of the window, and rather than adding a scrollbar, the rest of element is not shown (some element are half shown)

Here is an image :

[image]

and here is the xaml :

```
<Window x:Class="elexim.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:elexim"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow">

    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center">Employés </Label>
        <Separator Margin="20,0,0,0"/>

        <Grid Margin="0,20,0,0">

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <GroupBox Header="Liste Employés" Margin="20,0,0,0">

                <ListBox>
                    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <UniformGrid Columns="3"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

                    <local:employeeInfo/>
                    <local:employeeInfo/>
                    <local:employeeInfo/>
                    <local:employeeInfo/>
                    <local:employeeInfo/>
                    <local:employeeInfo/>
                    <local:employeeInfo/>
                    <local:employeeInfo/>
                    <local:employeeInfo/>
                    <local:employeeInfo/>
                    <local:employeeInfo/>
                    <local:employeeInfo/>
                    <local:employeeInfo/>
                    <local:employeeInfo/>
                    <local:employeeInfo/>
                    <local:employeeInfo/>
                    <local:employeeInfo/>
                    <local:employeeInfo/>
                </ListBox>
            </GroupBox>

            <GroupBox Header="Detail Employé" Margin="20,0,0,0" Grid.Column="1">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Label Margin="10">Nom</Label>
                    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

                    <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10">Age</Label>
                    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

                    <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Margin="10">Salaire</Label>
                    <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="0" 
                                Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                        <Button Margin="10" MinWidth="100">Valider</Button>
                        <Button Margin="10" MinWidth="100">Annuler</Button>
                    </StackPanel> 

                </Grid>


            </GroupBox>
        </Grid>

    </StackPanel>

</Window>
```

How can I make the listbox add a scrollbar rather than the current effect?

Comment: Problem is the main vertical `StackPanel`. It allows its to grow vertically as much as they want. Replace it with `Grid` or `DockPanel`

Comment: @dkozl there is no way to user StackPanel and limit the veritcal grow to the windows size?

Comment: You can limit the size of `StackPanel` but it will only affect it visible part. Vertical `StackPanel` will always give its children infinite height to grow. Analogically same thing will happen with width and horizontal `StackPanel`. That's how `StackPanel` is meant to work

Comment: ok thanks you @dkozl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use instead `Grid` of `StackPanel`:

Let me show an example:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center">Employés </Label>
    <Separator Grid.Row="1" Margin="20,0,0,0"/>

    <Grid Grid.Row="2" Margin="0,20,0,0">

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <GroupBox Header="Liste Employés" Margin="20,0,0,0">

            <ListBox>
                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <UniformGrid Columns="3"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

                <local:employeeInfo/>
                <local:employeeInfo/>
                <local:employeeInfo/>
                <local:employeeInfo/>
                <local:employeeInfo/>
                <local:employeeInfo/>
                <local:employeeInfo/>
                <local:employeeInfo/>
                <local:employeeInfo/>
                <local:employeeInfo/>
                <local:employeeInfo/>
                <local:employeeInfo/>
                <local:employeeInfo/>
                <local:employeeInfo/>
                <local:employeeInfo/>
                <local:employeeInfo/>
                <local:employeeInfo/>
                <local:employeeInfo/>
            </ListBox>
        </GroupBox>

        <GroupBox Header="Detail Employé" Margin="20,0,0,0" Grid.Column="1">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Label Margin="10">Nom</Label>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

                <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10">Age</Label>
                <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

                <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Margin="10">Salaire</Label>
                <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="0" 
                            Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                    <Button Margin="10" MinWidth="100">Valider</Button>
                    <Button Margin="10" MinWidth="100">Annuler</Button>
                </StackPanel> 

            </Grid>


        </GroupBox>
    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

or put you `StackPanel` inside of `ScrollViewer`:

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
  <StackPanel ... />
</ScrollViewer>
```